# npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND (ive tried everything)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I searched for this bug everywhere, I saw many stackoverflow answers and NOTHING worked. I'm desperate :(

I think it started after I tried to cancel an installation of a react app mid installing. It didn't even had node_modules, which would be my first thing to do: delete it, and reinstall it.
Regardless, it started getting stuck whenever I'd try to install it in a

```
[...............] / idealTree:final: sill idealTree buildDeps
```

And so after trying to install about 3 times I finally gave up and started searching for the answer and it lead me to try and reset my proxy or reset my internet or reset my computer or uninstall and reinstall nodeJS and nothing, nothing worked.

now when I try npm install -g npm or npm@latest it appears:

```
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! syscall dataddrinfo
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/npm failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxyhost
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly. See: 'npm help config'
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
[...]
```

What can I do, please?

I'm using windows.

When I enter npm config get proxy appears: `http://domain:8080/`

Comment: changing the protocol IPv6 worked for me :)